# Is saliva safe as a sexual lubricant for male masturbation?

Tags: penis, masturbation, saliva, circumcision, lubrication

I normally masturbate by licking my hand and using the saliva as a lube, because I'm circumcised and the thrusting motion I actually don't like—it can tear my penis skin since it's too tense.

Is using saliva safe, or does it contain bacteria that could cause me something? Obviously I can't contract a disease I didn't have, but maybe bacteria in the mouth should not reach the penis?

Answer (score 7):

Saliva is safe to apply to the sexual organs.  While it is true that [the mouth contains lots of micro-organisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_microbiology), the same varieties are also commonly thrive elsewhere in the body, and are all harmless against a normally functioning immune system.  Saliva also contains antibacterials, has skin-like acidity, and acts as a pH buffer.

The only concern is that it may also contain anything that has recently been in your mouth.  For example, using saliva as a sexual lubricant may be risky if you—

- have a topical infection around your mouth or lips, or have recently licked a location of such an infection,
- have recently eaten a food that can irritate sensitive skin or mucous membranes (e.g. vinegar, salt, or anything abrasive), or
- have recently kissed or had oral sex with anyone who might have a sexually transmissible illness.

In cases that you're unsure, other water-based lubricants sold in supermarkets and pharmacies are a safe alternative.